# Circle Progress Reading Bar

Tags: javascript, css

I have used the following code to produce a progress bar that is a circle instead of a line, for my blogposts!

Example page -> https://thefinterest.kinsta.cloud/hello-world/

Circle Progress Bar -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4RLS.jpg

I have 2 problems if you can help me out

1. i get the following error in console
   {
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
   at scrollProgress ((index):531)
   at (index):542
   at (index):513
   }
2. Is there a way to make the movement of the circle ease in?
   Kinda like ama zons news blogposts?

This is a test site i use to test things out, truth is that a circle progress bar is out of my depth but i would really like to nail it so i can use it on my sites!

There isn't something else that i found, exactly like this unfortunately on stackoverflow...

I thank you for any help!

```
<div class="scroll-progress-wrap">
   <div id="circ" class="p0"> 
        <div class="reading-time">4 min</div>
    </div> 
</div>
    
<style>
    .reading-time {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        width: 59px;
        line-height: 59px;
        margin-left: -30px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        }
    .scroll-progress-wrap { bottom:1em; right:1em }  
    #circ { width:67px; height:67px; font-size: 0.85em; color:#999; text-align:center; background:#ddd; border-radius:50% }
    #circ span { position:absolute; display:block; width:80px; line-height:80px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; background:#ffc; border-radius:50% }
    #circ.p0 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p1 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(93.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p2 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(97.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p3 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(100.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p4 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(104.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p5 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(108deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p6 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(111.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p7 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(115.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p8 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(118.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p9 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(122.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p10 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(126deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p11 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(129.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p12 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(133.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p13 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(136.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p14 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(140.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p15 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(144deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p16 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(147.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p17 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(151.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p18 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(154.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p19 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(158.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p20 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(162deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p21 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(165.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p22 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(169.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p23 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(172.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p24 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(176.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p25 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(180deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p26 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(183.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p27 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(187.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p28 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(190.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p29 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(194.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p30 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(198deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p31 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(201.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p32 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(205.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p33 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(208.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p34 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(212.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p35 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(216deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p36 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(219.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p37 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(223.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p38 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(226.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p39 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(230.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p40 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(234deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p41 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(237.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p42 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(241.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p43 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(244.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p44 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(248.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p45 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(252deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p46 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(255.6deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p47 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(259.2deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p48 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(262.8deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p49 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(266.4deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p50 { background-image:linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p51 { background-image:linear-gradient(-86.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p52 { background-image:linear-gradient(-82.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p53 { background-image:linear-gradient(-79.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p54 { background-image:linear-gradient(-75.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p55 { background-image:linear-gradient(-72deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p56 { background-image:linear-gradient(-68.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p57 { background-image:linear-gradient(-64.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p58 { background-image:linear-gradient(-61.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p59 { background-image:linear-gradient(-57.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p60 { background-image:linear-gradient(-54deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p61 { background-image:linear-gradient(-50.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p62 { background-image:linear-gradient(-46.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p63 { background-image:linear-gradient(-43.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p64 { background-image:linear-gradient(-39.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p65 { background-image:linear-gradient(-36deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p66 { background-image:linear-gradient(-32.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p67 { background-image:linear-gradient(-28.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p68 { background-image:linear-gradient(-25.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p69 { background-image:linear-gradient(-21.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p70 { background-image:linear-gradient(-18deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p71 { background-image:linear-gradient(-14.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p72 { background-image:linear-gradient(-10.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p73 { background-image:linear-gradient(-7.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p74 { background-image:linear-gradient(-3.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p75 { background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p76 { background-image:linear-gradient(3.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p77 { background-image:linear-gradient(7.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p78 { background-image:linear-gradient(10.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p79 { background-image:linear-gradient(14.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p80 { background-image:linear-gradient(18deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p81 { background-image:linear-gradient(21.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p82 { background-image:linear-gradient(25.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p83 { background-image:linear-gradient(28.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p84 { background-image:linear-gradient(32.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p85 { background-image:linear-gradient(36deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p86 { background-image:linear-gradient(39.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p87 { background-image:linear-gradient(43.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p88 { background-image:linear-gradient(46.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p89 { background-image:linear-gradient(50.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p90 { background-image:linear-gradient(54deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p91 { background-image:linear-gradient(57.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p92 { background-image:linear-gradient(61.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p93 { background-image:linear-gradient(64.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p94 { background-image:linear-gradient(68.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p95 { background-image:linear-gradient(72deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p96 { background-image:linear-gradient(75.6deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p97 { background-image:linear-gradient(79.2deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p98 { background-image:linear-gradient(82.8deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p99 { background-image:linear-gradient(86.4deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    #circ.p100 { background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, orange 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), linear-gradient(270deg, orange 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd) }
    </style>
    <script>
        (function(){
        function debounce(fn, ms){ 
            var time = null;
            return function(){
                var a = arguments, t = this;
                clearTimeout(time);
                time = setTimeout(function(){ fn.apply(t, a); }, ms);
                }
            }
        function throttle(fn, ms){ 
            var time, last = 0;
            return function(){
                var a = arguments, t = this, now = +(new Date), exe = function(){ last = now; fn.apply(t, a); };
                clearTimeout(time);
                (now >= last + ms) ? exe() : time = setTimeout(exe, ms);
                }
            }
        function addEvent(el, evt, fn, bub){
            el.attachEvent ? el.attachEvent('on'+evt, fn) : el.addEventListener(evt, fn, bub);
            }
        function scrollProgress(){  
            var top = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop, 
                dist = Math.round((top / (docY - winY)) * 100);
            (dist > 100) ? circ.className = 'p100' : circ.className = 'p' + dist;
            document.querySelector('#circ > span').innerHTML = dist + '%';
            }
    
        var body = document.body,  
            html = document.documentElement,
            docY = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight),
            winY = window.innerHeight || html.clientHeight,
            circ = document.querySelector('#circ');
    
        addEvent(window, 'resize', debounce(function(){ 
            docY = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight); 
            scrollProgress();
            }, 100), false);
        addEvent(window, 'scroll', throttle(scrollProgress, 100), false);
    })();
    </script>
```

Comment: The first question I would want to think your querySelector is returning null, maybe due to not being ready yet?

Comment: As for that type of movement, I would say you do it through CSS Animation and Shadow effect and 0-100% glow it while it moves. You seem on the right track however. But only commenting.

Comment: I cant think of a way to implement css animation to this unfortunately! Thank you for giving me a direction though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are targeting span in #circ, I don't see any span in the DOM.

Anyways, I've added a span in the demo, it fixed the undefined innerHTML issue
https://jsfiddle.net/twgofm91/1/

```
<div class="scroll-progress-wrap">
   <div id="circ" class="p0"> 
        <div class="reading-time">4 min</div>
     <span>0%</span>
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you are right! Thank you very much! I fixed it now!!